# How define a Type like `UIView<UITableViewDelegate>`(oc code) in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

An object of UIView or subclass of UIView and comforms to UITableViewDelegate protocol.

I need a generic type rather than a spesific type. So that developer who use it can define a freely. The oc code we can do like this:

```
@property (strong) UIView<SomeDelegate> *contentView;
```

Comment: In Swift 4: The type maybe like this: `typealias SomeView = UIView&SomeDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking you are just looking for something like this

```
class MyView : UIView, UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

You will most likely have to add UITableViewDatasource protocol as well

Answer (score 0):

Best practice you can use extension method for Current Class along with delegate or datasource:

```
class MyView : UIView {

}

extension MyView: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{

}
```

Comment: thank you, but I need a generic type rather than a spesific type. I want the developer who use my code to define the Type